# how to send message to service handler

Tags: android, handler

In my service i create handler for getting message and do some stuff work on the message.

```
   class ClientHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {
            case PUBLISH:

                connection.makeRequest(msg);
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

and

```
               switch (msg.what) {

                case PUBLISH:{

                    boolean status = false;
                    Bundle b = msg.getData();
                    if (b != null) {
                        CharSequence cs = b.getCharSequence(TOPIC);
                        if (cs != null) {
                            String topic = cs.toString().trim();
                            if (topic.isEmpty() == false) {
                                cs = b.getCharSequence(MESSAGE);
                                if (cs != null) {
                                    String message = cs.toString().trim();
                                    if (message.isEmpty() == false) {
                                        status = publish(topic, message);
                                    }
```

In my activity i have edit text and i want to sent setText.tostring as a message to my service I dont want to show anything in my activity then i don't want bind it . How can i send just a message to my service handler without binder? I dont want to use binder

Comment: Use a binder, this is what it's meant for. Why wouldn't you want to use it?

Comment: `Message` is `Parcelable`, so use it in `Intent` extras, but actually, does it really make sense? you can directly pass some `String` in the extras

Comment: @F43nd1r because I don't want to show anything on activity and why i have to use binder? is there any way for send message except binder?

Comment: @pskink I want to use Bundle then How can send this bundle to service handler?

Comment: send it in the `Intent`'s extras

Comment: @pskink by intent i can send a object to service but i want to send to handler!!! how can i sent an intent directly to handler?

Comment: you cannot, all you can do is pass it via extras to `onStartCommand` method, or you can use `Messanger` to send directly to `Handler` but it requires to implement `Service#onBind` method

Comment: @pskink this is not useful for me. i want to sent a message to handler. for example I can use of Messanger but i do not want to use binder.

Comment: no, if you want to use `Messanger` then you have to follow [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger), by doing so you will be able to send the `Message`s directly to your `Handler`

Comment: @pskink I know but by **Messanger** I have to use binder.I want to know does not any useful way!!

Comment: ok so whats wrong in bound services? and implementing `onBind` method? do you know how bound services work?

Comment: @pskink nothing .i want to know just is any better way to send message to handler.apparently there is any way.

Comment: so there is no such way, just bind to your service and use your `Messanger`, thats all

Comment: of course you could do that the other way: pass a `ResultReceiver` to your service, then the service returns a `Messenger` using `ResultReceiver#send` method and finally you can use `Messenger#send` method in your client, but is it really more easy way? no

Comment: @pskink . it is better that i use of binder . binder is very direct than ResultReceiver.thank you.

Comment: this is what I was saying from the very beginning - just follow Messenger pattern